# How can I get the points where two line shapefiles intersect?

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, ogr, intersect

I have two shapefiles that I want to compare and get the points where they cross. I would like to avoid opening QGIS or GRASS since I am trying to automate a process so I have been looking at OGR, GDAL, PostGIS, Python etc. I have tried several approaches but cannot get this to work. It appears that one big impediment is that I cannot install the Python package fiona. This seems to be a common problem for windows users. Does anyone have a solution that does not use fiona?

Comment: Install the version of [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

Comment: @gene version of what?  Are you referring to fiona?  I tried, it does not install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc39_ogr_layer_algebra and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/LayerAlgebra and download the Python script from 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr_layer_algebra.py

Running the script without arguments prints help

```
Usage: ogr_layer_algebra.py Union|Intersection|SymDifference|Identity|Update|Clip|Erase
                            -input_ds name [-input_lyr name]
                            -method_ds [-method_lyr name]
                            -output_ds name [-output_lyr name] [-overwrite]
                            [-opt NAME=VALUE]*
                            [-f format_name] [-dsco NAME=VALUE]* [-lco NAME=VALUE]*
                            [-input_fields NONE|ALL|fld1,fl2,...fldN] [-method_fields NONE|ALL|fld1,fl2,...fldN]
                            [-nlt geom_type] [-a_srs srs_def]
```

Test with two line layers "line1" and "line2"

```
python ogr_layer_algebra.py Intersection -input_ds line1.jml -method_ds line2.jml -output_ds intersection.jml -output_lyr intersection -f JML
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

ogrinfo intersection.jml -al
    OGRFeature(intersection):0
  R_G_B (String) = (null)
  MULTIPOINT ((539.400450838693 473.516276602798),(542.025830258303 253.638376383764))

OGRFeature(intersection):1
  R_G_B (String) = (null)
  MULTIPOINT ((424.76694772344 222.780775716695),(463.535287938115 497.29490975074))
```

Source layers and the result as an image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I can make this work. What is a .jml file though? I changed the call to supply my .shp files as inputs and tried to change the JML at the end to SHP.  This threw the error "Cannot find driver SHP". However, when I changed it back to JML, it produced an intersection file in .xml format (despite it having a .shp extension as I specified in my call). I'm not familiar with .xml format but, it being plain text, I can get the info I need from it.

Comment: JML is OpenJUMP JML format https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/jml.html but any format that GDAL supports can be used https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html. For shapefile output use driver name as "ESRI Shapefile". But be aware that intersection of two layers can contain points, lines, and polygons as a mixture and those can't be saved into same shapefile. With line layers you can get points but also linestrings if lines don't just cross but overlap. JML and XML formats accept all kind of geometries on the same layer.